# Webhook API send both "driver_canceled" and "no_drivers_available" events at a time

Tags: uber-api

I've noticed that Uber API started sending two events when Driver Cancels a ride. Both events are captured: `"driver_canceled"` and `"no_drivers_available"`

Here is an example (I left only status field and internal timestamp)

```
07:30:53.433 "status": "processing"
07:31:42.660 "status": "accepted"
07:33:39.351 "status": "no_drivers_available"
07:33:41.335 "status": "driver_canceled"
```

Or sometimes `"driver_canceled"` arrives a second earlier than `"no_drivers_available"`

I don't store `event_time` and can't tell original order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: This issue has been resolved.

Unfortunately, this is a bug in the Uber API backend. We'll let you know when this is resolved.